# Is there a way to programmatically change the function performed in a query?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm utilizing Grafana with InfluxDB as the database.

Say I have the following query

```
SELECT MIN("field_1"), MAX("field_1") FROM "measurement" WHERE $timeFilter
```

but I would like the user the ability to view the MEAN in the same panel instead

```
SELECT MEAN("field_1") FROM "measurement" WHERE $timeFilter
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Ideally the solution would be agnostic to `field_1` as I'd like to use it across multiple panels with different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Grafana dashboard variable e.g. `function` with values, which match InfluxDB functions: `MIN,MAX,MEAN,COUNT,LAST,...` and then use that variable in the Grafana InfluxDB query:

```
SELECT ${function:raw}("field_1") FROM "measurement" WHERE $timeFilter
```

so Grafana generates correct InfluxDB query syntax.

Even field can be dashboard variable, which can be automatically discovered with InfluxDB query `SHOW FIELD KEYS`.